# how to include bootstrap wizard into an angular application

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, wizard

I have the following `index.jade` file

```
html
  head
  ....
  ....
  body
  ....
  ....
  .container-fluid
      .row
        .span2
            h3 Links
            ul.nav.nav-pills.nav-stacked  
             li.active  
                a(href="link1") Link 1     
             li 
                a(href="link2") Link 2  
             li 
                a(href="link3") Link 3
        .span10
          .ng-view
        .span.5
           h1 
        .span3
          h3 Field Info
```

I want the bootstrap-application-wizard popup content found at (https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&ved=0CDoQFjAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Famoffat%2Fbootstrap-application-wizard&ei=49ckUoThI9LFsATIjIDoDw&usg=AFQjCNGGfJ85a77baLTojgaOHUK0miVHHg&bvm=bv.51495398,d.cWc)

as an ng-view, i.e. the window that opens after Open Wizard is clicked in the demo.html. I not sure how to specify ng-view width and height to a specific size like 750px by 375px etc.

I am new to javascript and angular and not sure how to incorporate such a design and specify ng-view size.

I have completed the following steps

1. Convert demo.html to demo.jade
2. added route information in app.js

   ```
   app.get('/demo', routes.demo);
   ```
3. rendered demo.jade in routes.js:

   ```
   exports.demo = function(req, res) {
       return res.render('demo');
   };
   ```
4. added angular controlls for `$routeprovider` in angular `app.js`

   ```
   .when('/demo', {
       templateUrl: 'demo',
       controller: DemoCtrl
   ```
5. the controller renders the following

   ```
   .....
   return $http.post('/demo', data).success(successCallback).error(errorCallback);
   ```

The page renders with Open Wizard highlighted but nothing happens when I click on it.

Comment: Hi, have you included the bootstrap-wizard.js? As well as the javascript code within demo.html in your code?

Comment: Yes, it's all there but no popup.

Comment: something to do with the wizard being a bootstrap modal. It does not open.

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap 2 or 3? The Modal Classes are different in 3 and the plugin you are using is built for Bootstrap2